# BizTalk support on EDIFACT for Postal Transactions

Tags: biztalk, edifact

We are in a need of understanding the capability of **BizTalk** on **EDIFACT** for **postal** **transactions**.

We need to understand whether the following postal **EDIFACT** transactions are supported by BizTalk.
1.  **PREDES**
2.  **PRECON** 
3.  **CARDIT** 
4.  **RESDIT** 
5.  **RESCON** 
6.  **RESDES** 
7.  **EMSEVT**
8.  **ITMATT**

Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

All of the supported EDIFACT schemas in BizTalk Server have become open source for a while now. You can look-up if a message is supported by checking this page: https://github.com/Microsoft/Integration/tree/master/BizTalk%20Server/Schema/EDIFACT

FYI: I did a search and haven't found a match for you.

Answer (score 0):

The document types is a standard defined by UPU (Universal Postal Union)
I do not know if these document wil ever be part of UNECE standardization

Biztalk is moving towards Azure Integration Services as we speak
But you should be able to adapt the schemas to other Edifact standards than those defined by UNECE

We duplicated schemas and adapted them back in the days for some local danish standardization like DAVID and GS1
The work is a bit tough but doable